# Метод RouteLink дает некорректный результат

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Столкнулся со странным поведением метода RouteLink. 
Имеем маршрут:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "TestRoute",
  url: "тест/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Для генерации url вроде **http://мойсайт.рф/тест** использую метод:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Test-link", "Test", new {  })
```

Все было прекрасно, пока не понадобилось ввести 4-й параметр:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TestRoute",
    url: "тест/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional, param4 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

теперь вызов:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Test-link", "TestRoute", new {  })
```

вместо ожидаемого пути возвращает **http://мойсайт.рф**. При этом, в тех местах кода, где хотя бы один параметр имеет непустое значение, метод RouteLink отрабатывает правильно:

```
@Html.RouteLink("My-test-link", "TestRoute", new { param1 = 1 })
```

НО! Если добавить в определение маршрута 5-й параметр, перестанет работать вызов RouteLink даже с заданным одним параметром!

Такое ощущение, что RouteLink "не терпит" более 3-х пустых параметров. Вопрос: это баг или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы в пустых параметрах null передаёте?

Comment: Можно null, можно new {  }, результат будет один. Если марштур определен с 5-ю опциональными параметрами, можно и new { param1 = 1 } передать, все равно неправильно ссылку сформирует. Похоже, что баг. Обойти его можно только с помощью * в объявлении маршрута, а потом парсить строку по "/" в экшене.